# How to create a shareable GSheet and get the URL?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Inside a google apps script, you can do

```
//create spreadsheet
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("Testing");

    //get public url
    var id = ss.getId()
    var file = DriveApp.getFileById(id);
    file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.EDIT);
```

When I run that code, it just gives error:

```
We're sorry, a server error occurred.
```

Comment: Often a server error is a temporary occurrence and not related to your code.  I just ran the code your provided without any error.  If the error persists it might be realted to quota issues.

Comment: Is there a place to check for quota?

Comment: [Apps Script quota](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) here, you might also want your Drive API and Sheets API quota usage in your [GCP console](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#viewing_your_quota)

Comment: Just got it working by starting a new file from scripts.google.com instead of clicking on Tools->scripts inside GSheet. Maybe that's a different script engine?

Comment: Yesterday I was having the same error but with the ContactApp service on a project that I added Google Cloud standard project. I made a copy of the script in order to test using the defalut Cloud project and it worked. Do your script has an default or an stardard Cloud project?